# How to add validation to html with a defined pattern

Tags: html, forms, validation

I have an input on an html form which I have set to have a pattern of A-Za-z and type text with a max length of 30 characters.

When I try to enter nothing I (correctly get an error that it is against the validation.

When I enter a name like Steve I get an error, even though it meets the pattern and when I enter 30 text characters it accepts the entry.

How can I get it to accept any entry up to and including 30 characters?

```
    <span class="form-group">
        <label for="c_name" class="form-label-bold" >First Name</label>
        <input name="c_name" id="c_name" class="form-control" type="text" 
        pattern="[A-Za-z]{30}" maxlength="30" required="true" title="Text 
        values only" th:field="*{firstName}" />
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit number of characters to be up to 30 you should change pattern to this `[A-Za-z]{0,30}`
Here's working example
https://jsfiddle.net/L0wt09gb/

Answer (score 0):

This accepts from 0 to 30 characters.

```
<span class="form-group">
    <label for="c_name" class="form-label-bold" >First Name</label>
    <input name="c_name" id="c_name" class="form-control" type="text" 
    pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,30}" maxlength="30" required="true" title="Text 
    values only"  th:field="*{firstName}"/>

 </span>
```